# iOS cllocationmanager gmt value

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to convert the user current timestamp value to GMT. For example, suppose right now I am in kolkata(India), and the time is 3:02 pm and date is 29/07/2015. But the GMT time is : Wednesday, 29 July 15 : 03 : 03(GMT + 5:30).
How should I achieve this including the same format?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
NSLog(@"Timestamp %@", newLocation.timestamp);
NSDate *date = newLocation.timestamp;
NSDateFormatter *dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateF setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a dd/mm/yyyy"];  //Set here your date format
NSString *dateString = [dateF stringFromDate:date];
```

Its working fine

Comment: Thank you. How should I display the timezone name, with it's format. Actually my client ask me to do this type of thing: Sun Jun 28 2015 00:00:00.000 GMT-0000 (Mountain Standard Time)

Comment: set your date format according to you . It will return  ... try once